# Stripe Payments with React, autofilling address possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe to handle credit cards, but right now I'm running into the issue where a user has to fill out their shipping/billing every time. Is it possible for me to use some predefined values for these? Right now, I have their shipping/billing saved to their account.

Additionally, I'm also trying to pass the charge amount to server side. I've tried wrapping it in a form and using a hidden input, but it always is undefined.

```
class Payments extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <StripeCheckout
            name="My Shop"
            description="Item" 
            amount={this.props.payment*100} 
            email={this.props.email}
            shippingAddress={true}
            billingAddress={true}
            token={token => this.props.handleToken(token)}
            stripeKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY} 
        >
            <button>Checkout</button>
        </StripeCheckout>
    )
}
```

}

```
export const handleToken = token => async dispatch => {
   const res = await axios.post('/api/stripe', token);

   dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data});
};
```

Comment: Can't you just pass in the saved values?

Comment: @fungusanthrax Not as far as I know. It allows for passing in email and a couple of other things, but shipping/billingAddress must be booleans.

Comment: Lets start here: are you having trouble creating a charge or creating a customer? I assume it's customer because a charge requires a customer. Are you using the latest version of Stripe?

Comment: Yes, using the latest version. However, I was under the impression customers are only used for recurring payments. I'm just doing a one time charge and would like to attach the currently logged in user's shipping and billing info that is saved to their account.

Comment: According to the docs if you want to include the user's shipping information you'll need to attach more than just true false but the predefined values.

Comment: I've been able to access the ship/bill info with args after submitting, but never as a preset value for the form. Where are you seeing this?

Comment: There's no way to pre-set these values in the form. 

As far as passing an amount or other form to your backend, you'd need to pass those values as part of your backend post --- I'm not super familiar with React conventions but maybe something like  axios.post('/api/stripe', {"token":token,"amount":2000});